# MySQL integrity constraint violation exception when deleting rows from tables

Tags: mysql

I am receiving the error below when running the below sql statements on very simple tables. the only foreign key used here is in the table `runs` and the foreign key is `runs.sample_id` which references `samples.id` . I'm not sure why I am receiving this error as I am trying to delete all the runs before deleting the samples in which they depend on. Code below:

java code:

String deleteRunsQuery = "DELETE FROM runs"; //delete rows from runs table
  String deleteSamplesQuery = "DELETE FROM samples"; //delete rows from samples table

stmt.executeUpdate(deleteRunsQuery);

stmt.executeUpdate(deleteSamplesQuery);

and the exception:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gc_image_relational`.`runs`, CONSTRAINT `runs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sample_id`) REFERENCES `samples` (`id`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1604)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1535)
at com.gcimage.relational.RelationalDatabaseTest.disposeDb(RelationalDatabaseTest.java:40)

Comment: Run this query first `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` after you are done set it to 1

Comment: how about cascade deletes, is that an option ? Turning on and off fk checks is a bit iffy. You either want integrity or you don't. So why pretend you have it (some of the time)

Comment: see [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33838108) of mine, and stop reading pretty much after "good, the cascade delete deleted the 1 row here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough rep to post a comment, I'm afraid. Maybe this may count as an answer anyway:

Your question is marked `mysql`, but you don't clearly state the programming language used; apparently it's Java. AFAIK Java works asynchronously, i.e. the engine doesn't wait for a statement to finish before executing the next. In this case it means that the second DELETE statement (on the `samples` table) will be triggered before the MySQL engine has finished DELETEing all the `runs`. Triggering the second DELETE in some sort of callback on the first would avoid this problem, or any other method to synchronize the two statements. Not sure how you'd do that, I'm not a Java programmer. Others may probably help you with that.

Comment: Not a shabby answer, and more than a comment

Answer (score 0):

Check your trigger OnDelete. Probably you try to add the new record after deleting and got a key duplication error